Can't communicate with Microsoft websites on my laptop
Since like 2 years, my laptop hasn't been able to open certain Microsoft websites/applications. I can't open

Microsoft forum (answers.microsoft.com)
Microsoft store
stuff that's shared on SharePoint
OneNote won't synchronize my teachers notes saved on their OneDrive

Rarely I've been able to use Microsoft store for short periods, the SharePoint stuff used to work too.
I wasn't a fan of Microsoft collecting telemtry data so I used stuff like Spybot Anti-Beacon for Windows but I've deleted it since the problems popped up, didn't solve it. I may have tried other apps and settings too, I can't remember. And it's not a network filter thing whatever since I can open these from other devices without a problem. What could be the problem? It's weird because Outlook, Word/PowerPoint on the web works, but these don't.
UPDATE: I'm just going to reinstall Windows...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What happens when you ping answers.microsoft.com?
And you could check the contents of your hosts file "C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts".
A lot of these telemetry blockers redirect certain domains to localhost (effectively blocking them).

I get a response from "e13362.dscb.akamaiedge.net [2001:918:ffcb:198::3432]", no loss. In the hosts file I've only found entries made by Docker, there used to be entries by Spybot Anti-Beacon but I've removed them long time ago.

Time to reinstall Windows. I am going to guess you didn’t reverse the changes those questionable applications made before you removed them and you don’t know what changes they actually made.

@Ramhound I've reinstalled Windows, the problem is now gone obviously. This time I will installl less questionable software...

While you're reinstalling the OS and so cannot recreate the issue in order to confirm an answer, Ramhound gave what is most likely the correct information: You didn't reverse or undo the changes you had the "Spyware" tool before you removed it.
The most legitimate of these tools usually work by modifying parts of your computer, including the HOSTS file, registry, and browsers, to prevent communication between your computer and known malicious hosts over the internet.
While you were trying to block Microsoft Telemetry, you likely blocked many normal Microsoft domains.
A good version of these tools will always create a backup of all changes made so that they can be reversed, but you would need the software to be installed in order order to restore the backup or undo the changes it made.
Note that this is assuming a legitimate, non-malicious or fakeware version of these tools. Back when the internet was younger there were a variety of these products that worked reasonably well and were legitimate. The problem is that as less technical people became aware of "adware", "spyware", and other terms for malicious software which might not be truly viral, unscrupulous developers recognized an opportunity and many, or even most, products now listed as "anti-spyware" or "anti-adware" are themselves malicious in some way. The more successful of these actually do a little bit of real spyware and adware prevention, but then also do their own little malicious acts.
Most mainstream antivirus products or "security suites" have integrated spyware and adware blocking and prevention and so there is no real reason to use additional products unless you have a specific target such as Microsoft telemetry, which is not really "malicious" in the barest sense of the word, but may still be unwanted.
To summarize: By installing that tool you probably opened yourself up to other malicious actions, and by uninstalling that tool you probably made it impossible to undo the changes that had been made.
Next time, do a little more targeted research on blocking Microsoft Telemetry manually rather than relying on a tool that claims to do this for you, or run an OS that doesn't have unwanted telemetry integrated into it, like Ubuntu Linux.
